# Is there a way to *toggle* squiggly lines in visual studio with a hotkey / keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to **toggle** the squiggly lines on or off in visual studio (not code)? I can disable them in the options but it would be nice if it was possible to enable and disable them with a hotkey.

I searched and cannot find a way to do this. My initial thought was to see, like in vscode, if I could bind any arbitrary option to a shortcut--and then bind this option to some hotkey. Can options only be set in the GUI?

Comment: How do you disable them in GUI?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. You can find all commands that you can assign shortcuts for in `Tools | Options -> Environment | Keyboard`

Comment: Hey @VladDX to disable them in GUI: `Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Display > Show error squiggles`